# Как возвращать переменную в функции?

Tags: javascript, функции, return

Как мне возвращать переменную mouth?

```
createCalendar(calendar, 2021, mouth + 1);

function ListenDate() {
    let left_arrow = document.getElementById('left-arrow');
    let right_arrow = document.getElementById('right-arrow');

    left_arrow.onclick = function() {
        mouth -= 1;
        console.log(mouth);
       return mouth;
    };

    right_arrow.onclick = function() {
        mouth += 1;
        console.log(mouth);
        return mouth;
    };
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Возвращать никак, только как-то так - функцию `calendarUpdate` создать, и из кликов отправлять значение туда - для изменения

```js
const calendar = document.getElementById('calendar_Probably?');
let mouth = 0;

createCalendar(calendar, 2021, mouth + 1);

const calendarUpdate = (newMounth)=>{
    calendar.value = newMounth;
};

const listenDate = ()=>{
    const left_arrow = document.getElementById('left-arrow');
    const right_arrow = document.getElementById('right-arrow');

    left_arrow.onclick = ()=>{
        mouth -= 1;
        console.log('L', mouth);
        calendarUpdate(mouth);
    };

    right_arrow.onclick = ()=>{
        mouth += 1;
        console.log('R', mouth);
        calendarUpdate(mouth);
    };
};
```